# How to change component when choosing by React button

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'd like it to be on my Dashboard component, to avoid having a component that's too heavy. Create several external components and display them according to the button chosen.

For example, if the user wants to display the Charts component, it's displayed, if he wants to display the Map component, it's displayed and removes the other one.

```
import React from 'react';
import {Button} from "flowbite-react";

function Dashboard() {
    
    const handleCharts = () => {
        return <Charts />
    }

    const handleMaps = () => {
        return <Maps />
    }
    
    return (
        <>
            <Button onClick={handleCharts}> Charts</Button>
            <Button onClick={handleMaps}> Charts</Button>
        </>
    );
}

export default Dashboard;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are couple of options available.

1 - using useState to conditionally display the components

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Button } from "flowbite-react";

function Dashboard() {
  const [displayComponent, setDisplayComponent] = useState(null);

  const handleCharts = () => {
    setDisplayComponent("charts");
  };

  const handleMaps = () => {
    setDisplayComponent("maps");
  };

  if (displayComponent == "charts") {
    return <Charts />; // if you want to again display the buttons, add a button to setDisplayComponent(null) in <Charts />
  }

  if (displayComponent == "maps") {
    return <Maps />; // if you want to again display the buttons, add a button to setDisplayComponent(null) in <Maps />
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Button onClick={handleCharts}>Charts</Button>
      <Button onClick={handleMaps}>Maps</Button>
    </>
  );
}

export default Dashboard;
```

2 - using Modal

- as you are using `flowbite-react` you can use [Modal](https://www.flowbite-react.com/docs/components/modal) component Provided from the library